# iOS use of declared identifier in buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a very new to iOS development but I have dabbled in Java and C before.

I'm trying to create a simple timer application and when the user presses 'start', the button text will turn into 'reset' but the compiler throws me a "Use of undeclared identifier 'btnStart'"

I've taken out the rest of the code because everything worked run until I tried to change the button text.

I'm pretty sure its correctly declared in the .h file and I'm thinking it might have to do with adding another @property argument for the button itself but that didn't really work. How do I properly declare a button then?

Thanks

my ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)btnStart:(id)sender {

   [btnStart setTitle: @"RESET" forState: UIControlStateNormal]; //Error shown here
}
```

my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDisplay;

- (IBAction)btnStart:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnStop:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: make sure you have  added referencing outlet for your button.Everything works fines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please declare button IBOutlet in .h or .m file where you have declared --

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDisplay;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnStart;
```

and use it like this

```
   [self.btnStart setTitle: @"RESET" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I swear I tried to do this but maybe I didn't link the GUI properly. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 2):

The sender should be the button itself. Try this

```
- (IBAction)btnStart:(UIButton *)sender {
   [sender setTitle: @"RESET" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: This works for only the case where I call the button from itself. But if I wanted to change its title from another function I would need the "self" answer from -ashForlos, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can set title of the button for two states in viewDidLoad function like this

```
[btnStart setTitle: @"RESET" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[btnStart setTitle: @"Start" forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

and in your function use this code

```
- (IBAction)btnStart:(id)sender {
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
[btn setSelected:!btn.isSelected];
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, the problem is he doesn't have `brnStart` declared as a button, he has `btnStart:` declared as a function.

Comment: He just want to change the name on the button when it state changed and it is possible with this code. And also this function don't need to make a new function to revert bak to its name. Just changing the state will work well.

Comment: I meant the first part where you have `[btnStart setTitle:...`, `btnStart` doesn't exist as an ivar there